# Prove that each $f_n(x) = \frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

How can I prove that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}, f_n(x) = \frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ is Borel measurable where $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued function? I was thinking of first proving that each $f_n(x)$ is continuous, but I am not sure if that is even true. Are there any other ways of proving this statement?

Comment: What is the definition of $f$?

Comment: @MarkSaving $f$ is just a real-valued function (I don't have any conditions that $f$ satisfies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you know is that $f$ is a real-valued, this can't possibly be the case because it implies every function is measurable. For given any function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we could define a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in [0, 1)$, $f(x) = g(x) + f(x - 1)$ if $x \geq 1$, and $f(x) = f(x + 1) - g(x + 1)$ if $x < 0$. Then $f_1(x) = g(x)$.

But not every function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. For example, the characteristic function of any non-measurable set will be non-measurable.

On the other hand, if we know $f$ is measurable, this follows from a few facts:

1. Continuous functions are measurable when the measure spaces have the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Hence, $-$ and multiplication by a constant are measurable functions.
2. The composition of measurable functions is measurable.
3. If $f, g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, then $f \times g : X \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(f \times g)(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ is measurable.

So we have $f(x + 1/n)$ is measurable, because it is the composition of measurable $f$ and measurable function $x \mapsto x + 1/n$. Then the map $x \mapsto (f(x + 1/n), f(x))$ is measurable. Compose this with subtraction to get the measurable map $x \mapsto f(x + 1/n) - f(x)$. Compose this with multiplication by constant $n$ to get that the map $f_n$ is measurable.

Note that result (3.) can actually be generalised as follows:

1. If $A, B$ are measure spaces and $A \times B$ has the product $\sigma$-algebra, then $A \times B$ is the product of $A$ and $B$ in the category of $\sigma$-algebras. That is, given maps $f : X \to A$ and $g : X \to B$, the map $x \mapsto (f(x), g(x)) : X \to A \times B$ is measurable iff $f$ and $g$ are.
2. If $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces, then the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel algebras of $A$ and $B$ is exactly the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $A \times B$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $f$ is measurable in this case.  If so then since the composition of measurable functions is measurable, and since $x+\frac{1}{n}$ is measurable, so is $f(x+\frac{1}{n})$.  The rest follows from the fact that linear combinations of measurable functions are measurable.